# Extract v, r and s from signature for use with pyethereum.transaction library

Tags: python, pyethereum, web3.py

Given an unsigned transaction, constructed using pythereum.transaction, and a signature, created by signing the transaction's hash with a private key, how do I extract the v, r, s values from the signature so they can be added to the unsigned transaction to sign it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r`, `s` and `v` values are different slices (in that order) of the signature created by signing a hash value. Refer: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/pull/19

The ranges of each slice are in the first message of the thread at the above link. Also, note the part about adding 27 to the value of `v` if `v` is 0 or 1. The reason for this is an issue whose link is given in that message.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pyethereum to sign with the private key, then `Transaction` objects already parse out `r`, `s`, and `v` for you. They are made available as attributes of the same name on the transaction object.

In [the code](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/transactions.py#L135) for `transaction.sign(key)`, it sets the variables here:

```
self.v, self.r, self.s = ecsign(rawhash, key)
```

(But then your transaction object would already be signed, so you wouldn't need to do any more work, and probably don't need `r`, `s`, and `v` anymore.)